# C# Getthumbnail2 Method problem in my PDM Add-in

Tags: c#, solidworkspdmapi

I'm coding an add-in for solidworks pdm. I use epdm interop library. But i got some issues to Getthumbnail2 Method. 
I use in this way:

```
IEdmFile5 file5 = vault.GetFileFromPath(filePath, out IEdmFolder5 folder5);
            var version = file5.CurrentVersion;
            IEdmFile15 file15 = (IEdmFile15)file5;
            var obj = file15.GetThumbnail2(version);

            Image imgPreview = PictureDispC.PictureDispConverter.Convert(obj);
            imgPreview.Save(GetTempPath() + parcaadi + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            imgPreview.Dispose();
```

I encountered this error code:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x8004040B
  İleti=HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0x8004040B
```

At This line;

```
var obj = file15.GetThumbnail2(version);
```

Method decleration: https://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/epdmapi/epdm.interop.epdm~epdm.interop.epdm.iedmfile15~getthumbnail2.html

Example usage:https://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/epdmapi/Get_File_Thumbnail_by_Version_Example_CSharp.htm

Comment: Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is that it has to be logged in to work.

```
IEdmVault5 vault5 = new EdmVault5();
var vaultName = vault5.GetVaultNameFromPath(filePath);
vault5.Login("admin", "", vaultName);
IEdmFile5 file5 = vault5.GetFileFromPath(filePath, out IEdmFolder5 folder5);
```